# fql_query returns "Array" instead of name

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to create a simple fb app that retrieves the name of the user using fql_query.

Code :

require_once 'facebook.php';

$appapikey = 'xxxx';

$appsecret = 'xxxx';

$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret) ;

$user_id = $facebook->require_login();

$q = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid='$user_id'";

$name = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($q);

echo "Name : $name[0][name]";

Output:
Name : Array[name]

Can you tell me what's going wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake is in this line:

```
echo "Name : $name[0][name]";
```

you are including $name[0][name] in quotes, this should be

```
echo "Name : {$name[0][name]}";
```

or

```
    echo "Name : ".$name[0][name];
```

Answer (score 0):

An FQL query always returns an array, even if there is only one item in the result. Think of the result as rows in a normal SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Any time that I use arrays or database/API calls in PHP I print_r($array_name) to see what was returned. So this:

```
$name = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=$user_id");
print_r($name);
```

Should return this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => First Last
    )
)
```

Another thing, I never put tick marks around values/variables in FQL.

```
$q = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=$user_id";
$name = $facebook->api_client->fql_query($q);
```

But when you print the value you *should* put single quotes around the reference to the named index (in this case, 'name') and you should not wrap it all in double quotes:

```
echo "Name : " . $name[0]['name'];
```